# Camera recording fails on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-10, video-recording

I am using the ozeki camera sdk to record 1/2 cameras ... however when I record on windows 10 the solution works perfectly ... but with windows 7 the solution fails to multiplex the video on the 2nd or 3rd try... in more details ... the audio and video files are generated but when compressing or multiplexing for the real video file nothing is generated ... what would be the problem ??

*I installed .net framework v 4.5.2 and 4.7 
*The project version is 4.5.2 
*The camera light is on which means it is recording.
*The camera is connected through USB 
*The camera fails to record even with selecting to record with 1 camera

Comment: After changing Net versions did you do a clean build?  Did yo ubuild on Windows 7 or Windows 10?  Do you have the same USB driver on both machines?  You may of installed the standard Microsoft USB driver instead of the Vendor Driver.

Comment: @jdweng yes I already built multiple times the project ... I do not install any drivers on both machines supposing that the windows automatically install them as i have a camera viewer that test the camera ... as well as the camera records the first time and sometimes 2 times ... and I have an old version using direct show it records but sometimes it throws an empty video ... do you suggest though trying a vendor driver ??

Comment: You can check the name of the driver installed by looking at Device Manager.  The driver comes with the camera (or download). Does the camera works with camera viewer?  Are you using same options in the Camera Viewer as you application?

Comment: Yes it works in the camera viewer ... and I tried all kind of settings with the camera ... I dont have the driver for the camera it is not mine but I guess if it is not correct it would be streaming in the camera viewer right ??

Comment: Using the standard Microsoft Driver some options may work and other may not work.  You should be able to find the driver on the working machines and then install on non working machines.

Comment: Will this include recording two or three then no ??

Comment: I asked the owner he told me that it is a plug and play camera is that true ?

Comment: Plug and Play just means when the driver will automatically install.Plug and Play will have a pop up saying a driver is needed.Then ask if it should search for driver or let user select folder for installation.If you select search for driver the Microsoft Driver is usually the one that gets installed.If it is working two or three times then an older version of driver may be installed that contains errors.  It possible using the Microsoft will work most of the time.  Windows 7 machines are slower so the driver may be dependent on speed of machine and you need to use an older driver for Win 7.

Comment: So you suggest looking for the latest drivers ?? The issue is that i tried with multiple cameras but with the same windows drivers as well

Comment: The driver that works best with the speed of the Window 7 machine.

Comment: I tried the win 7 latest driver from logitech website didnt work aswell

Comment: Looks like driver may be sensitive to speed of machine.

Comment: I installed the logitech software it records very well ... so I dont know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed the latest constructor drivers on Windows 7 ?

Indeed, in Windows 10, drivers are automatically installed.

Comment: Do you mean the camera driver ? For example that logitech created ?? I assumed that win 7 installed it as it records the first 2 times as well as i have a camera viewer that streams the camera correctly ... though I have an old version with direct show that records but sometimes it throws an empty .avi file

Comment: Did you test again with c# after the logitech installation? After running logitech can you read the USB serial port settings?  The logitech software may be using a different speed.  Can you also read camera settings?